# Async/Await nodejs support?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

Just a small problem that I can't fix. I'm on Node v8.1.1 and I try to use async/await but it doesn't work. My code snippet looks like this :

```
const axios = require('axios');

const TOKEN = '...';

const httpClient = axios.create({
    baseURL : 'https://myhost/api/',
    headers : {
        'Authorization': `Token ${TOKEN}`
    }
});

try {
    const resp = await httpClient.get('users?limit=200');
} catch(e) {
    console.error(`Fail !\n${e}`);
}
```

And when I try to run it, I get this error message and nothing happen :

```
/Users/mathieu/workspaces/galactic-tools/index.js:13
    const resp = await httpClient.get('users?limit=200');
                       ^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:533:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:575:3
```

Async/await should be supported by Node in version 8 directly, right ?
In the doubt, I tried to run with `node --harmony-async-await index.js` and `node --harmony index.js` without result.

Comment: `await` is only valid inside `async` functions.

Comment: It works :) but It is weird Oo. Do you know why node can't handle `await` usage directly from root ?

Comment: Because it's not allowed by the specification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't say if async/await is supported in node8, but you could try wrapping the try/catch in a function like so:

```
async function callService() {
    try {
        const resp = await httpClient.get('users?limit=200');
    } catch(e) {
        console.error(`Fail !\n${e}`);
    }
}
callService()
```

since it should be clear which block will have async behavior. Also for this to work, httpClient.get() should return a `Promise`. Make sure it's so.

Comment: Indeed, I checked before to ask the question

Answer (score 12):

async/await is supported by node v8.x. However, await has to be inside async function. They always come in pair.

Update:
Top level async/await is also supported in the latest nodejs:
https://pprathameshmore.medium.com/top-level-await-support-in-node-js-v14-3-0-8af4f4a4d478